# Finding and editing gnome terminal colors without gui

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal, colors

I like the color scheme editor for the gnome terminal and all, but I hate not being able to work with color values, whether it be hexidecimal or some other form. How do you find out the color values of your profile's theme and is there a file somewhere where you can edit these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stored in gconf `.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml` as 12 digit hex values (where Default is the profile name).

You can set them with gconftool-2 e.g.

`gconftool-2 -s -t string /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/foreground_color  #65657b7b8383`

there is also background_color and palette which takes a list of 16, colon separated values, (no idea what these correspond to though).